# Can't find out where this bracket goes?

Tags: java, android

I can't figure out why Eclipse is complaining about my second bracket for the "OnClick" method...

I know its a simple thing, but I just can't seem to fix it!

Code for my activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CallService cs = new CallService();
    TotalTime = TotalTime + (cs.EndTime - cs.StartTime);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+TotalTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } // <-- Why is it complaining about this bracket?!
}
```

Comment: In the future, post your code here instead of making us look for it. Also, `TotalTime` isn't named using normal Java conventions--following those conventions aids readability.

Comment: Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: just add `});` before your last shown bracket. That will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

For every open parenthesis or bracket you need to close it, you also need to finish every statement with a semi-colon. The compiler wants `});` added:

```
   // You open these, so you need to close them in order
   //                       v                           v
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       //                          v
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Perform action on click

           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+TotalTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.show();
       }
   //  ^    
   }); // This is what the compiler wants
// ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your're missing this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+TotalTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}); // <------------- Close the parenthsesis!!
```

Comment: you forget one **}**  (for closing View.onClickListener)

Comment: Hmm.. still cant get it..why is this still wrong? 

http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/6INd0afyi

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You **gave an** `extra bracket` at the Wrong Place, and **missed** a `bracket` and `a brace` with a `semicolon`.

**- Wrong:**

```
         new View.OnClickListener()) // Dont add ")" here.
```

**- Correct:**

```
         new View.OnClickListener()
```

**- Missed:**

```
           } );
```

**2.  Replace this part with yours in the program, and it will work for sure...**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // Perform action on click

                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+TotalTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   toast.show();
           }

       } );
```

**3.** For **further ease i am posting** below the **entire working code of yours....**

**///////////// The Whole onCreate() with the corrected code///////////////**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CallService cs= new CallService();

       TotalTime = TotalTime + (cs.EndTime-cs.StartTime);

       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // Perform action on click

                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+TotalTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   toast.show();
           }

       } );   

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to put your code in an IDE such as eclipse. It will generally reflect the point of compilation error and so you don't have to put an extra effort searching for such errors. In case you want to format your code just do the following steps in eclipse

while your cursor is in the coded region

press ctrl + A                          // it selects all code

then press ctrl + shift + F            // this formats your code

now you can easily spot starting and ending point of parenthesis and your code looks nicely formatted.